# Strategy for Octopus variable substitution in config.js that is webpacked in jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, webpack, octopus-deploy, variable-substitution

I am working on an ES6 AngularJS project where I am using webpack to bundle everything into `dist/app.js`.

The CI/CD stack I am working with is SCM - Jenkins - Octopus:

1. Updates to my code are pushed to a repository
2. Jenkins clones the repository, calls `npm install` and `gulp` which uses `gulp-webpack` to bundle & minify everything from one entry point and puts it to `dist/app.js`
3. Post-build, Jenkins packages the app into a nuget pkg and pushes it to Octopus Deploy where the app is deployed to IIS

The octopus project is working in multiple environments and I have to have a way to replace some configuration variables depending on the environment. For that, Octopus provides a "Substitute variables in files" deployment steps.

When I didn't use a module bundler and ES6, I would just have a configuration file that sets some angular constants which I then used. I would have a `config.js` file and a `config.template.js` file. Octopus would replace the variables in the `config.template.js` file and I would just set it to replace `config.js` with `config.template.js` post-deployment.

Now however, I am just using a plain `config.js` that exports the variables I need to use, which I then import in the files where it is relevant (like a file that contains an angular controller function).

With this setup, I cannot do the substitution the same way I did it before, because my `config.js` will just get included inside `dist/app.js`. could anyone help me come up with a strategy on how to achieve this ? I was thinking to do the `config.js` - `config.template.js` swap before the build and then make Octopus replace the variables in the whole `app.js` bundle but that seems rather inefficient.

Answer (score 5):

We had something similar in our build-process and were equally perplexed. We settled on an in-code token replacement solution using JS itself to determine if the token had been replaced so it will work in local-dev (pre-deployment).

We added code like this:

```
// config --------------------------
(function () {
    // These values will be replaced by Octopus during deployment.
    var configuredApiUrl = "#{Api:Url}";
    apiUrl = (configuredApiUrl[0] !== "#") ?
        configuredApiUrl : "http://api.local/v1";        
})();
```

Then we setup variable substitution on the output file.

I hope this helps!

Comment: So just for clarity, in octopus, you have set the substitution for the output bundle that contains all the code/modules ?